# How to run executable program from a trigger?

Tags: triggers, odbc, exe, advantage-database-server

How would I create a trigger to execute a `.exe` file on `UPDATE` or `INSERT` for a table in Advantage Database Server?

I am new to ADS and I can't really find much documentation on what I want. The support section of their website is a maze.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try the Online help files?

http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/webhelp/Advantage10.1/index.html

In particular:

http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/webhelp/Advantage10.1/master_triggers.htm

http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/webhelp/Advantage10.1/master_trigger_containers.htm

> Advantage triggers can be implemented in a variety of containers: SQL scripts, .NET Assemblies, Win32 DLLs, COM objects, or Linux shared objects.

To create such a trigger you can use the Advantage Data Architect (ARC32).

Right click on the table and click "Triggers".